# Can't connect to http://localhost:54321

Tags: r, h2o

I like to to run the lilikoi example code with the mock data provided by the lilikoi R package, however, I am stuck at the lilikoi.machine_learning() command due to a connection error with H2O.

I downloaded the H2O file and unzipped it in the R Terminal, but now I cannot connect to http://localhost:54321 as indicated by your website (https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zygmund/4/index.html).

Below is the error message I get, copied from my R console:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\LUISEB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6HnISl\file2abc38ab39e6/h2o_Luise_Bellach_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\LUISEB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6HnISl\file2abc5e38704f/h2o_Luise_Bellach_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0_361"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.361-b09, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 582 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster timezone:       Europe/Berlin 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
    H2O cluster version:        3.38.0.1 
    H2O cluster version age:    4 months and 11 days !!! 
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_Luise_Bellach_gwz511 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   3.51 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    16 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  16 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    R Version:                  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) 
Warnung: 
Your H2O cluster version is too old (4 months and 11 days)!
Please download and install the latest version from http://h2o.ai/download/
  |=========================================================================================================================| 100%
  |                                                                                                                         |   0%Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: Operation was aborted by an application callback
[1] "Job request failed Unexpected CURL error: Operation was aborted by an application callback, will retry after 3s."
```

This goes on multiple times and the % bar doesn't move. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Best

Dr. Luise Bellach

I downloaded the H2O file and unzipped it in the R Terminal, but now I cannot connect to http://localhost:54321 as indicated by your website (https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zygmund/4/index.html).

Comment: what is the output of those logs mentioned at the top of the error? can you not just use h2o directly from r? as described [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/ac53e79085dce5802f8996ff97f63dc01a1fe180#1-downloading-h2o-3)

Comment: Hi Matthias, the files mentioned in the log do not exist. And when I try to download h2o directly as indicated via your link, i only get H2O Version 3.38.0.1 & for the lilikoi package i need h2o Version 3.38.0.4 ; to update this, i need to download the package directly via their website & i cannot connect to their local host

Comment: okay, that's not their localhost tho, this is your own localhost, and it's not working because h2o is not being installed because of the error

Comment: hi Matthias, i just managed to download the package through an alternative way, now it works, thanks!

Comment: very good, please post an answer with this alternative way so that it may help someone else :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way for downloading the latest package:

1. define where you want your ZIP file to be downloaded to (i created a Downloads folder in my working directory) and download from  http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html
2. run this in the terminal

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip h2o-3.38.0.2.zip
cd h2o-3.38.0.2
java -jar h2o.jar
```

3. go through the dialoge in the terminal to install r (not python)
4. install via the console

```
install.packages("~\Downloads\h2o-3.38.0.4\R\h2o_3.38.0.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

5. load the library

```
library(h2o)
```

Troubleshooting: make sure to have the fitting Java Version installed (e.g. Version 8)

Alternatively: here is also a code posted by H2O: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-in-r